# Altering file name with php

Tags: php

I'm getting info out of a RSS feed.

How can I change a file name with php?

Say I have this filename:

```
http://anyurl.com/any_file_name_200.jpg
```

I need to change the last part of it "200.jp" into another number, say "800.jpg". I need to do this dynamically, because "any_file_name" will always be different, but all the file names have the same structure in the end "123.jpg"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace`:

```
$filename = 'any_file_name_200.jpg';
$newFilename = preg_replace('/\d{3}\.jpg/','800.jpg',$filename);
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends what do you mean by "always the same structure".

If you mean XXX.jpg (Three digits + ".jpg"), then you simply have to remove the 7 last char and replace them by whatever you want. **Many** ways to do that, check PhP functions related to string in the PhP manual.

If you mean it will always end by _XXXXXXX.jpg (UNDESCORE + WHATEVER + ".jpg") then you could `explode()` the string, remake it until the very last part of the array, and replace it

Comment: I mean exactly that: XXX.jpg (Three digits + ".jpg")  How do I do that with php?

Comment: Well, then as I said, many ways to do so. Check the length of your string, repaste until `string length - 7` (or 8, depends how you get it) and write whatever you want, quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

To rename a file on your server, use the `rename()` function ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)).

Example:

```
#Prefix is everything before the number. 0 is the start, -7 counts from the end
$prefix = substr( $url, 0, -7 );

if( rename( $url, $prefix . '800.jpg' ) ) {
  #Yay! We renamed...
}
```

See [rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) and [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the rename function in php , here is the link for it in the manual :
[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)

and here is an example :

```
rename('sample.jpg' , 'sample2.jpg');
```